# Not able to print all non empty values in nested json using java

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, gson

My purpose it to print Json only with non empty objects. As in attached picture i have empty objects which i don't want to print them. It doesn't matter which library to choose either Gson or Jackson , etc'
[image]

Tried so far a lot of combination but in didn't worked

My data structure is :

```
Map<AWSRegion, List<SecurityGroupDiff>> listEntry...

public class SecurityGroupDiff  {

  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) ... // on all fields/objects
    private String groupId;
    private String groupName;
    private String vpcId;
    private String owner;
    private String type;

    private List<IPPermissionDiff> ipPermissionDiffs;
```

}

Tryid so far:

```
private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper().
                    setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL).setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY).setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);


    MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                    .writeValueAsString(listEntry)
```

the result is still the same ...

```
{
  "CANADA" : [ { }, { }, { }, { }, {
    "ipPermissionDiffs" : [ { }, { }, { }, { } ]
  }, { }, { }, { } ],
  "ASIA_SIDNEY" : [ {
    "ipPermissionDiffs" : [ { }, { }, { }, { }, { } ]
  }, { }, { }, { }, { }, { }, { }, {
    "ipPermissionDiffs" : [ { }, { }, { }, { } ]
  }, { } ],
  "EU" : [ { }, { }, { }, { }, { }, { }, { }, { }, {
    "ipPermissionDiffs" : [ { }, { }, { }, { }, { }, { }, { } ]
  }, { } ]
}
```

thanks

Comment: What would the result be if empty elements would not be printed? Should it be `"ipPermissionDiffs":[]`, `"ipPermissionDiffs":null` or nothing at all? If the latter, should that apply to the parents as well? If so, the output would be an empty string because that object is effectively empty.

Comment: @ Thomas , the output should include only keys that non empty , in my case no json keys shoud appear at all ( cause all is empty)

Comment: Well, the problem is that empty objects and empty arrays are not nothing, i.e. `"ipPermissionDiffs" : []` is not empty by that definition. Hence you'd probably have to do the filtering yourself, i.e. remove any empty map/json object or list/json array from the bottom up.